# webpack options has an unknown property 'hotOnly'. Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, build, webpack-dev-server

I am running the command `npx webpack-dev-server --mode development` in my `react` application and getting the preceding error.

```
[webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'hotOnly'. These properties are valid:
```

Below is my `webpack.config.js` file.

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          presets: ["@babel/env"],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "https://localhost:3000/dist/",
    hotOnly: true,
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
};
```

Any idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: Webpack 5 has major changes, this article helped me https://frontendguruji.com/blog/invalid-options-object-dev-server/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like the updated version of `webpack` doesn't support the property `hotOnly`, we should use the option `hot` instead. You can see a GitHub issue associated with this [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12597#issuecomment-773942191).

```
  devServer: {
    hot: "only", // hot:true
  },
```

The latest versions automatically apply HotModuleReplacementPlugin plugin when you set hot: true, so please check you don't have HotModuleReplacementPlugin in your plugins if you have hot: true/hot: "only". You will get a warning as " ***[webpack-dev-server] "hot: true" automatically applies HMR plugin, you don't have to add it manually to your webpack configuration.***" if you have the preceding settings.

```
plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
```

If you are getting error "*static heartbeatInterval = 1000; SyntaxError: Unexpected token =*", make sure to use the node version is `>= 12.13.0` as per the guide [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md).

If everything is done, you should be able to see an output as preceding when you run `npx webpack-dev-server --mode development`.

[image]

Thanks, @Tushar Mistry for providing the migration guide.

Below is my completed `webpack.config.js` file.

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          presets: ["@babel/env"],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
    },
    port: 3000,
    devMiddleware: {
      publicPath: "https://localhost:3000/dist/",
    },
    hot: "only",
  },
};
```

Or you can also use the old version as below.

```
"webpack": "4.41.5",
"webpack-cli": "3.3.10",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.10.1"
```

Answer (score 20):

So devServer|Webpack config is related to Options for [webpack-dev-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server)
If your webpack is using webpack-dev-server version 4 you should use this [migration guide](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md)

```
// your v3 config
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "https://localhost:3000/dist/",
    hotOnly: true,
  },
```

in v4 will be

```
devServer: {
    // contentBase
    static : {
      directory : path.join(__dirname, "public/")
    },
    port: 3000,
    // publicPath
    devMiddleware:{
       publicPath: "https://localhost:3000/dist/",
    },
    // hotOnly
    hot: "only",
  },
```

Comment: I was getting the question title's error except with unknown property 'contentBase' in error instead of 'hotOnly'. Using your "in v4 will be" suggestion fixed this for me. Thanks Tushar.

Comment: Also there is a missing comma after `devMiddleware` property which causes error.

Comment: This helped me because I was having an issue with the contentBase property and your post taught me that the property was deprecated and changed to "static". Thanks!

Comment: How do I get v3?

Answer (score 0):

For me, comma was missing after devMiddleware property causing error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing an older version of webpack

```
"webpack-dev-server": "3.10.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact issue above from the LinkedIn course "**Building Modern Projects with React**".

My project has these versions

**"webpack": "^5.91.0",

"webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",

"webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"**

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'] },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    static : {
      directory : path.join(__dirname, 'public/')
    },
    port: 3000,
    devMiddleware:{
       publicPath: 'https://localhost:3000/dist/',
    },
    hot: 'only',
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
};
```